# delayed initialization?

Tags: c++, singleton, reference

could somebody please explain why this happens? I have written the following:

1) a WindowManager class which is implemented as a singleton and has an `Instance()` method, defined like so:

```
static WindowManager * instance_;
//...
WindowManager * WindowManager::instance_ = 0;
WindowManager & WindowManager::Instance()
{
    if (!instance_)
        instance_ = new WindowManager();
    return *instance_;
}
```

2) a `WindowManager::createWindow` method that returns a reference to a newly created window, defined like so:

```
Window & WindowManager::createWindow()
{
    windows_.push_back(Window());
    return windows_.at(windows_.size() - 1);
}
```

3) a `Window::print` method that prints a message inside the window

In my main program, I have written the following:

```
ui::Window & win1 = ui::WindowManager::Instance().createWindow();
ui::Window & win2 = ui::WindowManager::Instance().createWindow();
win1.print("First window");
win2.print("Second window");
```

This does not work! Only the second call to `print` is executed (for `win2`).
However, if I change the order, like so:

```
ui::Window & win1 = ui::WindowManager::Instance().createWindow();
win1.print("First window");
ui::Window & win2 = ui::WindowManager::Instance().createWindow();
win2.print("Second window");
```

then everything works as expected. If anybody could shed some light on this situation, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem was that in `createWindow` I return a reference to an object created on the stack, which is destroyed when the method ends.
Changing `windows_` from `std::vector<Window>` to `std::vector<Window *>` and modifying everything else accordingly solved my problem.

Comment: Thats not your cause, but that would solve the real problem

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have quick example which illustrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct T
{
    int id;
    T(int id) : id(id)
       { cout << "created " << id << endl; }
    T(T const& t) : id(t.id)
       { cout << "copy: " << t.id << endl; }
    void print(char const* m)
       { cout << id << ": " << m << endl; }
};

vector<T> ts;

T& create(int id)
{
    ts.push_back(T(id));
    return ts.at(ts.size() - 1);
}

int main()
{
    // Uncomment these lines and compare results
    //int const max_windows = 10;
    //ts.reserve(max_windows);

    T& t1 = create(1);
    T& t2 = create(2);
    t1.print("t1");
    t2.print("t2");
}
```

Compile and run as it is and see what is printed to stdout.
Then uncomment `reserve()` call, compile and run once again and compare with previous output.

The problem is that `std::vector::push_back` causes reallocation of the data internally. This invalidates all references, pointers or iterators to vector elements you've obtained before the reallocation.

Comment: Std::deque does not suffer from this problem, and is nearly as fast as a vector for most purposes.

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime, I managed to work around the problem by changing my vector to hold pointers to objects. What is the preferred c++ way to hold a series of objects inside a manager class? A container of objects, or a container of pointers to objects?

Comment: See @MooingDuck comment. Also, you can have a hybrid: collection of shared_ptr.

Comment: Note that std::deque _will_ still have this problem if you erase any elements from the middle.  Std::list/set/map ensure that references are not invalidated ever.